# Кодировка MessageBox в Lazarus

Tags: winapi, кодировка, lazarus

При использовании MessageBox в лазарусе в зависимости от того `application.MessageBox` это или `windows.MessageBox`, либо кнопки на английском, либо заголовок и текст в окне не корректный (кракозябры, иероглифы).

Answer (score 1):

Помогло добавление функций, задействующих Winapi в отдельный unit и последующая смена его кодировки на ansi.

Comment: Напишите по-подробнее - как вы это сделали. У меня вообще в проекте на одной форме messagebox нормально отображается, а на другой форме в этом же проекте - вместо русских букв - кракозябры.

Answer (score 1):

Такая же проблема. Кракозябры в сообщении. Решил её использованием другой диалоговой функции, позволяющей вручную прописать русский текст на кнопках - **QuestionDlg**.

Пример:

```
    if QuestionDlg('Заголовок','Текст сообщения',mtConfirmation,
      [mrYes,'Да', mrNo, 'Нет', 'IsDefault'],'') = mrYes then ...
```